# Zsh terminal not working correctly in fresh Manjaro install

Tags: linux, terminal, desktop, zsh, manjaro

recently I've been experimenting around with different Linux distros, I settled with Manjaro Linux. First I installed it on my laptop, everything went fine. When i was prompted to choose a terminal environment I chose **zsh** since all my life I have used bash. Needless to say I really enjoy zsh.

However, when I installed Manjaro on my desktop PC zsh behaves differently regarding colors, auto-completion, and highlighting. I presume that something went wrong during the install.

This is how the terminal looks on my laptop:
[image: Good Terminal]

This is how the terminal looks on my desktop PC:
[image: Bad Terminal]

Please take into account that both installs were made using the latest Manjaro Architect, both with the exact same steps taken. KDE is my Desktop environment in both cases.

I hope the information I have given is enough, because this is clearly out of my realm of expertise. If you think there is any more info I can provide please tell me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as it turns out, Manjaro Linux Architect didn't finish configuring the zsh shell during setup for some odd reason.

I managed to fix it modifying the following script/config file: ~/.zshrc.
I followed the documentation found in the  [Zsh Arch Wiki Entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh).

After modifying the file to my liking I ran a "chmod +x ~/.zshrc", and rebooted. It worked.

My terminal now works as intended, though setting it up was a very tedious process. I recommend using a skeleton of the config and modifying it to your personal preference. (Examples are provided in the wiki entry.)

I hope my findings are useful in case someone gets the same problem.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem but it was my fault. I installed [autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump) with pacman and manually then ended up with the same screenshot as seen in the question. The problem is solved after removing the one installed with pacman:

```
sudo pacman -Rns autojump
```

The actual problem was `PATH` variable was getting corrupted somewhere and most of the commands couldn't be found such as `ls`, `mv`, `rm`...